# SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

Tags: json, ajax, forms, record

I can record data in my db but ajax loading doesn't inter in success method. What's the problem?

```
error: "SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input
    at Object.parse (native)
    at n.parseJSON "
```

**record_data.php**

```
<?php
$type=getPar_empty("type",$_GET,"");
$new_nome=$_GET['new_nome'];
$new_cognome=$_GET['new_cognome'];
$new_email=$_GET['new_email'];
$new_lingua=$_GET['new_lingua'];
if ($type=="add_user"){
  $stmt=null;
  $stmt=$db->prepare("INSERT INTO newsletter_utenti(email,abilitato,nome,cognome,lingua,lista,data_creazione,unsubscribe) VALUES('$new_email',1,'$new_nome','$new_cognome','$new_lingua','manual',now(),0)");
  if (!$stmt) {
    log_msg($db->error);
    die();
  }
  $stmt->execute();
  $stmt->close();
  $db->close();
}
?>
```

**script**

```
   $("#salvaBtn").click(function(){
  var nome = $('#nome').val();
  var cognome = $('#cognome').val();
  var email = $('#email').val();
  var lingua = $('#lingua').val();
  var dataString = 'nome='+nome+'&cognome='+cognome+'&email='+email+'&lingua='+lingua+'&type=add_user';
  $.ajax({
    type:'GET',
    data:dataString,
    url:"record_data.php",
    success:function(result) {
              $("#status_text").html(result);
              $('#nome').val('');
              $('#cognome').val('');
              $('#email').val('');
    },
    error:function(xhr,status,error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });
});

$('#adduser').submit(function (){
  return false;
});
```

**form**

```
<form name="adduser" id="adduser" method="GET" action="#">
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group m-b-30">
                <p>E-mail</p>
                <input class="form-control" type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="indirizzo e-mail" email required>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group m-b-30">
                <p>Nome</p>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="nome" name="nome" placeholder="nome">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group m-b-30">
                <p>Cognome</p>
                <input class="form-control" type="text" id="cognome" name="cognome" placeholder="cognome">
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-3">
              <div class="form-group m-b-30">
                <p>Lingua</p>
                <select class="form-control" id="lingua" name="lingua">
                  <option value="it">IT</option>
                  <option value="en">EN</option>
                </select>
              </div>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-embossed btn-primary m-r-20" id="salvaBtn" value="Aggiungi utente"></input>
              <div id="status_text" /></div>
            </div>
          </form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

your jquery ajax call should include

`dataType: 'html',`

to explicitly state that the data coming back from the server is **html**

in fact you're taking `result` and putting it straight into the DOM node with id `statusText`

---

Then you have to fix a major issue: your PHP script **is not returning** (`echo`ing) **any data** !

---

**Bottom note:** you **really** should use **mysqli** for your db queries http://php.net/manual/en/book.mysqli.php and also use prepared statements to build up the query (instead building up the SQL query by concatenating strings).

Comment: Thank you, Paolo, You've solved my issue! I also appreciate your precious help and clarification. 

I have a noob question for you: Why the PHP script has to return data?

Thank you in advance

Comment: The PHP script does not necessarily have to return data back. It may do its job and exit silently. But in your example the AJAX query expects data back so the PHP script is supposed to send something! If the PHP script may fail for some reason (ex. unable to write to the DB) then having the script returnig success/failure status and having the frontend javascript code checking for that status is a good practice.