# $.ajax() returns syntax error: Unexpected end of json input

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, ajax

So I'm working on a website where I have to implement a chat, currently the whole thing is running on localhost. 
I'm getting this error:

> SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input

and can't figure out why. I have googled a little but can't find an answer, that actually works. I actually did this yesterday, on another computer and that worked super, but today it won't work and I can't figure out why.

Thank you for the great answers.

```
$(function() {
    updateChat("updateChat", null);

    $(".chat-form").submit(function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        if ($(".chat-form input").val() != "") {
            updateChat("sendMessage", $(".chat-form input").val());
        }
    });

    setInterval(function() {
        updateChat("updateChat", null);
    }, 3000);

    function updateChat(method, message) {
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "action/chat.php",
            data: {
                function: method,
                message: message
            },
            dataType: "json",
            success: function(data) {
                console.log(data);
            },
            error: function (request, status, error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        })
    }
})
```

Comment: Open developers console and see raw output of your php script.

Comment: Do you know how to do that from xampp?

Comment: Developers console is in your browser.

Comment: Im leaving SO for good.

Comment: did you in fact load the required (jQuery) libraries? If it worked on one site and not yours, then something went South.

Comment: i'm sure jquery is loaded

Comment: maybe your JSON's malformed or not sending JSON, I don't know or the HTML

Comment: or `})` you didn't close off the last bit with `;` - i.e.: `});` try that.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [SyntaxError: Unexpected end of JSON input](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40086609/syntaxerror-unexpected-end-of-json-input)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most likely there's an error or warning in your PHP code being displayed, and because you are expecting only json, that causes the syntax error.

There are a few ways to find out what's going on:

- open the developer console in your browser and see what the response is the network tab
- check your PHP error log
- temporarily change your `dataType` to `html` and you'll see your `console.log(data)`

Comment: *"Most likely there's an error or warning in your PHP code"* - To which I asked earlier as to why the php tag, but I removed my comment about it since they edited to remove the php tag. If that is relevant, then they should add the php for it and the tag.

Comment: @markusrytter "what" worked? You not sending JSON as I stated in comments. IMHO, the question's unclear and as to what you did to fix this. I don't want to rain on this guy's parade but I don't see what's so different here that hasn't been said in comments.

Comment: I changed the dataType to html

Comment: @markusrytter Which in a nutshell is what I said in [this comment](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43377416/ajax-returns-syntax-error-unexpected-end-of-json-input#comment73817158_43377416) (*"or not sending JSON"*) but you failed to respond to it. I had a feeling that you weren't, and using an `html` type is what I had in mind; I figured you would have known that.

Comment: U should be getting more thumbs up I think.

Comment: When your error reporting class turns out to be the thing that is undefined >< . . . the html trick worked nicely.

Comment: I had a similar issue. In my instance I had `dataType: 'json'`, but the server's method mapped to the `POST` was returning `void`. As above, using `html` or just removing the reference to `dataType:` fixed the problem for me.

Answer (score 1):

I was getting this error due to my backend php function NOT returning a response as it should have been. It was returning nothing.  My parent function that should have been returning the response was calling a child function that WAS returning a response, but the parent function wasn't passing that child return back to the ajax call.

Answer (score -1):

Another possible culprit for these type of errors could be an improper python "shebang" on your back-end (server side) script.

In my particular case I had ajax call to python cgi script via Apache web server and I could not find a more descriptive error message at front-end debug tools. However, Apache logs indicated that the back-end script had problems importing a one of the python scripts because the interpreter did not recognize it. After checking the "shebang" of that back-end script sure enough it had the wrong interpreter specified because I just copied a template file over and forgot to modify it..

So, check your "shebang" at the top of your script to make sure it points to correct interpreter. Example:
[image]

Answer (score -1):

For MVC  controller you must return a valid JsON

```
return new JsonResult() { Data = new { test = 123 } };
```

instead of

```
return new JsonResult();
```